# Problems with SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm getting the below error when I try remote access (via ssh).

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
```

Problem:

```
[daniel@daniel_pc ~]$ ssh root@192.168.0.212
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
```

But this is only happening when I try remote access with ssh, if I try to ping it, for example, I get it normally, as in the example below.

```
[daniel@daniel_pc ~]$ ping 192.168.0.212
PING 192.168.0.212 (192.168.0.212) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.212: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.212: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=8.39 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.212: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.620 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.212: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=1.09 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.212 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3033ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.620/2.799/8.396/3.237 ms
```

The problem began to happen after I added the "config" file to "/home/daniel/.ssh/", and I fed "/ etc / hosts" with the host information I wanted.

After the problem happened I deleted the "config" and deleted the information from the "hosts", but the problem continues.

It is worth remembering that when I try to access by the root user I usually access access.

```
[daniel@daniel_pc ~]$ su
Senha:
[root@daniel_pc daniel]# ssh 192.168.0.212
Last login: Wed Jul 26 10:44:46 2017 from 192.168.0.99
```

---

INFO: Fedora 25

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 11 17:13:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c1bm.rdu2.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Apr 11 17:13:24 UTC 2017

[daniel@daniel_pc .ssh]$ ssh -vv root@192.168.0.238
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/daniel/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 2: include /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 8: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
```

Comment: What are the contents of /etc/hosts and ~/.ssh/config ? It looks like ssh resolves 192.168.0.238 to an empty string.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of your .ssh/config file.